# IntellijIdea, how to remove all commits information

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I'm using IntellijIdea and I  have a project with a big number of commits. I'm creating a new repository so the idea is to remove all those commits information, like date, author and all. And publish all as a first commit.

Any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delete your `.git` folder and initialize your git repository again with the `git init` command.

Comment: I did that but is not detecting the changes that i have. I dont have any to push neither commit.

Comment: If IJ doesn't recognize the changes, you can click `Refresh` button on Version Control panel. After that you can create your first commit and push it to the repository.